# std::map: can it copy and move keys after they have been inserted?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, std

In other words, is it safe to store pointers to keys from a map? Or is it possible for the map to copy and move keys during its lifetime, thus invalidating existing pointers?

The docs say: "Iterator validity: No changes." Does that mean the answer to my question is "no, they cannot be copied or moved"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `std::map` container template provides a *node-based* container, which means that iterators and references to a container element are never invalidated until the element is erased from the map. So you can hand out element key addresses to third parties as long as the map is alive and the element remains within it.

Comment: Great, thanks for clarifying. Do you by chance know where this is specified in the docs?

Comment: Would it be invalid for an implementation to use index-based iterators so that the validity is guaranteed but the actual elements are moved around in memory? If not, where is this stated?

Comment: @Chris: [associative.reqmts]/9.

Comment: @6502: See previous comment. I'm not sure that it says anywhere that it's allowed to "keep an iterator valid" but change the element it points to. Note, for example, that `vector::insert` with sufficient capacity only keeps iterators *before* the insertion point valid, so I'd say no, that's not intended to be possible. In any event, what would happen to the iterator to the last element if you erase another element?

Comment: @KerrekSB: just imagine the map storing elements in a vector of nodes where indexes play the role of the node address (i'm not saying this would be a good idea!) and where adding new elements may reallocate the vector. The iterators would remain valid (including the past-the-end iterator) but the element address itself would change. Is this forbidden? IIRC a container is free to make as many copies and moving operations as it wishes on the contained elements...

Comment: @6502 - [associative.reqmts]/9: "The insert and emplace members shall not affect the validity of iterators **and references** to the container, and the erase members shall invalidate only iterators and references to the erased elements." (emphasis added).

Comment: @6502: That would be absolutely forbidden (see Pete's comment). But even if your iterator said "take the ith element in key order", I think that would still be problematic.

Comment: @PeteBecker: oh, ok... that should read "...iterators and references to elements in the container..."

Comment: @6502 - yes, that's poorly worded.